# how to implement count total discount value and total gst value along count total row use in invoice using jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel, math, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying implementing a count total  "DCS discount" value and total "gst" value along count  total "row" use in invoice using jQuery.

example

[image]

I tried this in jQuery code but it not work

```
$('tbody').delegate('.quantity,.price,.gst,.dsc', 'keyup', function() {
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  var quantity = tr.find('.quantity').val();
  var price = tr.find('.price').val();
  var gst = tr.find('.gst').val();
  var dcs = tr.find('.dcs').val();
  var totalprice = quantity * price;
  var totaldiscount = (totalprice * dcs) / 100;
  var totalvatable = totalprice - totaldiscount;
  var totalvat = (totalvatable * gst) / 100;
  var totalamount = totalvatable + totalvat;


  tr.find('.totalamount').val(totalamount);
  total();
});

function total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.totalamount').each(function(i, e) {
    var totalamount = $(this).val() - 0;
    total += totalamount;
  });
  $('.total').val(total + ".00");
}
```

my view

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control quantity" name="qty[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="QTY" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control gst " name="gst_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="GST" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control dcs " name="dcs_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="DCS" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="number" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control price" name="purchase_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="RATE" value="" required pattern="" numbers="" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalamount" name="" id="validationServer01" placeholder="AMOUNT" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this might solve your problem, put this in your controller and call it in the blade template

```
$total_amount = YOURMODEL::all()->sum('THECOLUMN');
or
$total_amount= YOURMODEL::all()->pluck('THECOLUMN')->sum();
```

Let me know if there is still a problem

Comment: i want to code in jQuery only when it inserting data it need to calculate view only